# Name error in class when importing my script file to another from

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, import, nameerror

I wrote some code in a script file script.py

```
from functools import reduce

class Operators:

    def __init__(self, names):
        
        self.op_name = []

        for name in names:
            self.op_name.append(name)
    
    def __matmul__(self, other):

        if type(other) is Operators:
            
            new_op_list = self.op_name + other.op_name
            
            return Operators(new_op_list)

    def __str__(self):

        return ' @ '.join(map(str, self.op_name))



class Single_Ket:

    def __init__(self, label: tuple, coeff, operator = []):

        self.label = label
        self.coeff = coeff
        self.operators = operator
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        
        Operator_Str = str( eval(' @ '.join(map(str, self.operators))) )
    
        if type(self.label) is tuple:
            
            return '{} * {} @ | {} >'.format(self.coeff, Operator_Str, ', '.join(map(str, self.label)))
        
        else:
            return f'{self.coeff} * {Operator_Str}.|{self.label}>'



if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    Jp = Operators(['Jp'])
    Jm = Operators(['Jm'])


    ket_1 = Single_Ket((1, 1), 1, [Jp @ Jm])

    print(ket_1)
```

which works fine when I run it.

However, when I import test.py into another file test.py and run

```
from script import*

Jp = Operators(['Jp'])
Jm = Operators(['Jm'])
    
ket_1 = Single_Ket((1, 1), 1, [Jp @ Jm])

print(ket_1)
```

I got the error message 'NameError: name 'Jp' is not defined'. Given I defined Jp in test.py, I don't understand the reason why I get name error.

What is the way to fix this, or is there any related article I can look at to fix this?

Comment: it's your eval, don't use it. You haven't defined JP in test.py, you defined it in the `if __name__ == __main__`.

Comment: Is it generally a bad thing to use eval in my code?

Comment: Very bad thing, there aren't many places where you should use it

Comment: do you wish to explain what the code does? What are you trying to accomplish? I'll try and help you make it work.

Comment: Hi thanks, I went back to my code and remove the eval thing. It works fine now : )

Comment: Awesome! You can add your own answer to the question if you wish or remove it